# Visibility in jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery, css, html, function, accordion

I'm creating my own Jquery accordion, and it's almost complete. But, I would like to know if it's possible to make the accordion start closed without declaring a `$(".wrap-faq  li  p").slideUp();` before the function, because when it loads it slides up.

I would like to charge the document with the accordion already closed. I've tried (in CSS) to use `display:none;` and `visibility: hidden;`, but to no avail. This is my Jquery code:

```
$(".wrap-faq  a").on("click", accordion);
$(".wrap-faq  li  p").slideUp();

function accordion() { 
    if ($(this).attr("class") != "active") {
        $(".wrap-faq  li  p").slideUp();
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $(".wrap-faq a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
}
```

I'll also leave you [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xtatanx/3zvgY/) jsFiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding display none to the `<p>` tag seems to do the job. Is this what you were looking for?

```
.wrap-faq li p {display:none;}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zvgY/1/)

Answer (score 0):

is this are you looking for ?

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
```

sorry this only fixes, reopen opened accordion bug...

Comment: both of them were what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(".wrap-faq  li  p").hide();
```

Instead of slideUp()